# WooCommerce custom theme development best practices

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I made an e-commerce website before where I copied the template files inside WooCommerce and edited them to display the content how I wanted. But now I know of shortcode and WP_Query which can also be used to get the products / categories etc.

So what I am wondering is which method is best and are there times where you would use one method over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a time and place for different methods. Nix the shortcode though. *Generally* speaking you shouldn't "hard code" shortcodes into a custom theme (there are exceptions of course), unless you mean that you want to build in a shortcode that theme-users have access to.

That said, if you want to *emulate* WooCommerce's current style/layout with your own flair, or you want to *extend* the current templates, use the current template override method. Note this will lead to your theme getting "stale" at some point. WC does a decent job of not changing the templates too often, but it does happen and your theme *should* accommodate when that happens.

If you're doing something different with a list of products entirely that's not necessarily supposed to look ingrained in the WooCommerce structure, then you can use a custom WP_Query or Database query to accommodate your needs.

So effectively:

- If you want to *tweak*, *extend*, or *reduce* the current WooCommerce structure, use template overrides
- If you want a fully customized solution or need WC Products in a different capacity, use a custom query method.

Answer (score 0):

Everything woocommerce do well.
No need to use WP_Query separately

If you wants customize the theme you can use `add_action()` and `add_filter()`
Also you can modify css.

Hooks Referance: 
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/